# Null pointer exception while reading properties file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven-3

```
propsdatabase = new Properties();
InputStream dbin = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/properties/database.properties");
propsdatabase.load(dbin);
```

I am reading my database connection details via a properties file which is named 'database.properties' in a folder named 'properties'. Jus below the root directory.

The code was perfectly working fine when the jar was exported in Eclipse.

But I used Maven project in IntelliJ to get the jar . It throws NUll pointer exception .

Since the Value of dbin is NULL.(I  printed and checked also).

I conclude that the path is not recognised to read the file.

Now The things are fine with IntelliJ .

While doing an export as jar in Eclipse the jar although contains propertioes folder IT is not detected. pl help

Comment: Looks like your property file is not on your classpath (in this case inside your jar)

Comment: Yes .. thats right . any Idea how to overcome this

Comment: Is the file /properties/database.properties in the jar file that intellij is using?

Comment: How_do_I_add_resources_to_my_JAR http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_add_resources_to_my_JAR ???

Comment: Move your file to $rootproject/src/main/resources/properties/database.properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that `getResourceAsStream` is returning null is that the `/properties/database.properties` file is not in the Maven classpath.

Move your properties folder to under `/src/main/resources` folder and when Maven creates a jar file, the `/properties/database.properties` resource will be included, and you'll stop getting the NPE.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `getResourceAsStream` is no doubt returning null. I suspect that your jar file doesn't include the file. Try running:

```
jar tvf yourfile.jar
```

to check. Next, check the build steps for the jar file. It's hard to say what's wrong without seeing the build file, so please edit your question to include that information if it doesn't leap out at you when you look at the steps.

Comment: The jar in Eclipse works for me . But for my team mates it does not recognise the path still. How to handle in Eclipse (Export as jar file)

Answer (score 0):

Does your maven build step include the properties file in the jar? Check the jar-file that is produced. If you don't know how you can always rename it and add a ".zip" at the end and open it.

Comment: I find that there is no properties file in my jar

Comment: Then that's your problem, you have to include the file (or all *.properties files or something) when building the jar file.

Comment: Have to add something like this to your maven build: <directory>src</directory> 
    <includes> 
     <include>**/*.properties</include> 
    </includes>

Comment: sure .. In maven + IntelliJ I put my properties in resource folder .It wrks fine

Comment: OK that's another way, but hard to copy the files back to a non-maven build then, such as run it in eclipse.

Comment: Hi ..Pulsar as u mentioned its a problem in Eclipse now . Do u have any suggestions . Kindly help

Comment: Same suggestion as before, move the properties files back to where you had them and to add support for the maven + intellij add the above include to the maven file.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to read the properties file using the path and a FileInputStream:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
FileInputStream input = null;
try {
   input = new FileInputStream(new File(CONFIGURATION_FILE));
   properties.load(input);
}catch(...){...}
```

Comment: Hi Daniel ... This works only if I give CONFIGURATION_FILE = "C://...//database.properties"   It requires a hardcoded path of the properties .

Comment: You are right, I though you want to have the properties files outside the jar. As Guillaume Polet and Andrew Newdigate point out, the solution will be to move database.properties to src/main/resources